# Python -- How to apply split() function to an entire column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a python assignment whereby I need to analyze a yelp dataset. The following are the columns of the dataset:

```
Index(['review_id', 'user_id', 'business_id', 'stars', 'useful', 'funny',
   'cool', 'text', 'date'],
  dtype='object')
```

The following is one example of an entry from the dataset:

[Example of entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atmOx.png)

I'm looking to group all the entries by their stars score (1-5), display what percentage of restaurants received that score, and finally show what the average word count of the reviews in each star count is. Each value in the "text" column contains a restaurant review in string form -- these are the words I need to count.

The average word count is where I'm stuck. I have succeeded in writing a code to find the average **character count** but not the average **word count**. See the following code:

`reviews_df["review_length"] = reviews_df["text"].apply(len)`

```
def text_length_statistics(reviews_df):
    subgroup_stars = reviews_df.groupby("stars")["review_length"]
    subgroup_statistics = subgroup_stars.agg(["size", "mean"])
    print(subgroup_statistics)
```

The code produces the following output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmL7C.png)

This is nearly perfect but the mean values show the mean character counts. I've been told that applying the split() function to a string and then running len() through that new string will allow me to count the number of words in a string. However, in the case of this code ((`reviews_df["review_length"] = reviews_df["text"].apply(len)`), I'm already applying len via the .apply(len) function to an entire column from a dataframe -- essentially, on a list of lists. **This does not work...would anyone be able to provide a solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a lambda function into your `apply` call:

```
lambda x : len(x.split())
```

I'd normally show it *in situ*, with output, but you failed to complete your posting with the necessary demonstration data.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference, may I know what you mean't by "necessary demonstration data"? Should I have posted the dataset up here for reference?

Comment: See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Off-site links are not acceptable, you didn't specify your problem, and your code does not produce any output.  We need the input data, stand-alone code, and both the actual and desired output.  I compressed that into one phrase, expecting that you've been through the intro tour and posting guidelines.  If not, revisit those (I've been through at least four times, myself).

Answer (score 0):

we can do this by following the method also.

```
reviews_df["review_length"] = reviews_df["text"].str.split(" ").str.len()
```

Hope this helps